# How do I invoke a method on a class using attributes?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection

I want to invoke a method on a class that i have a reference to. The method that I want to call has a custom attributes. Currently I can find this attributes and call the property of my class Attribute.

is there a way to invoke that method ?

PS/ The project is written in vbnet, but I think the solution is the same in c#.

Comment: Could you provide more details or the code smple. Your question is not clear yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *can find* the attributes I guess you have the `MethodInfo` of that method(s). Simply call the `MethodInfo.Invoke` method, you have to specify the instance of the object you want to use (or `null` if it's a static method) and all the parameters to pass to the method (in the same order of the prototype).

For example if you have to invoke a method with this prototype:

```
void Foo(string name, int value);
```

And you have a function to find that method (making a search for a given attribute):

```
MethodInfo FindMethodWithAttribute(Type attributeType, Type objectType);
```

You can find and invoke that method (of a hypothetical object `anObject`) with this code:

```
MethodInfo method = FindMethodWithAttribute(
    typeof(MyAttribute), // Type of the "marker" attribute
    anObject.GetType()); // Type of the object may contain the method

method.Invoke(anObject, new object[] { "someText", 2 });
```